# Android Studio's navigation problem throws error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android-studio

So i have been trying to get a button to work and navigate through to another fragment but only accessible from that button, which i want separate from my bottom nav bar, that one works

the main issue i find is that when trying to add these actions just like i would with the bottom navigation it throws an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity

can anyone point me in the right direction and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I think its to do with confusion with the navhost fragments? MAybe they think it's the same and overwriting eachother? Idk, ive been going in circles, and disabling my bottom navigation bar doesnt fix it either.

Heres my Main Activity Code, along with the java fragment with the button i want to have this action.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
ActivityMainBinding binding;

BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView; //initializing the bottom nav bar from activity_main again

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//changing content which is based on the activity_main class, think of activity_main as the  main driver class, where everything is activated at
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
//FROM HERE
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

//TO HERE THESE PARTS THROW THE EXCEPTIONS

    
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Along with the code for my navigation graph, the other actions in there, are for my bottom navigation, which is why one fragment has 2 actions, 1 foor that button, shared with the same nav _graph,

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/fl1">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fl1"
    android:name="com.example.appnav.FirstFragment"
    android:label="fragment_first"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
        app:destination="@id/fl2" />
    <!--These fragments (pages) are all linked by the action button with where they end up on click -->
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fl2"
    android:name="com.example.appnav.SecondFragment"
    android:label="fragment_second"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_secondFragment_to_frag3"
        app:destination="@id/fl3" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fl2_to_flp"
        app:destination="@id/flp" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fl3"
    android:name="com.example.appnav.frag3"
    android:label="fragment_frag3"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_frag3" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fl3_to_fl4"
        app:destination="@id/fl4" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fl4"
    android:name="com.example.appnav.frag4"
    android:label="fragment_frag4"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_frag4" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fl4_to_fl5"
        app:destination="@id/fl5" />
</fragment>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fl5"
    android:name="com.example.appnav.fragt"
    android:label="fragment_fragt"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_temp"/>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/flp"
    android:name="com.example.appnav.pay_frag"
    android:label="pay_frag"
    tools:layout="@layout/pay_frag" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_flp_to_fl_pdone"
        app:destination="@id/fl_pdone" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fl_pdone"
    android:name="com.example.appnav.fl_pdone"
    android:label="fragment_fl_pdone"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fl_pdone" />


</navigation>
```

This is the fragment with the button involved
basically trying to use the action from the nav_graph, and take u to the next fragment, in this case a fragment which is not on the bottom navigation

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

private FragmentSecondBinding binding;

@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState
) {

    binding = FragmentSecondBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    return binding.getRoot();

}

public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    binding.buttonSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(SecondFragment.this)
                    .navigate(R.id.action_fl2_to_flp);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NavController` wants `view` not `context`. Just change your `context` to `view` as below.

```
binding.buttonSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            NavHostFragment.findNavController(view)
                    .navigate(R.id.action_fl2_to_flp);
        }
    });
```

If not solved, let me know.

Comment: Hi, it seems to have a new issue,'findNavController(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)' in 'androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment' cannot be applied to '(android.view.View)'

Comment: @CrimsonRainer can I know that you use `Botton Navigation` or `Navigation Drawer` in your app?

Comment: Bottom Navigation, But that part of the code is irrelevant as the bottom navigation works, what im trying to use is another button to navigate to anotehr fragment which wont be on bottom navigation, as im going to setup a confirmation fragment

Comment: @CrimsonRainer I tested it a few months ago in my app but couldn't get a positive result. My `navigationController` did not navigate my fragment reason of `Navigation doesn't have the controller of all fragments`. Wait until some developer solves this issue. Otherwise, it is easy to navigate fragment to fragment position via `Navigation Drawer`.

Comment: Alright i'll try and change it up a bit, thanks for letting me know!